# Get relative path from absolute URI for EObject

Tags: eclipse, path, eclipse-emf, emf

I have an URI for an EObject, which looks like this:

```
file:/C:/runtime-run123.product/Project1/examples/Apple.ecore#/
```

I get the URI by calling `EcoreUtil.getURI(ePackage)`, where ePackage is an instance of the class `EPackage`.

How can I get the relative path from that URI? The result should be: `/Project1/examples/Apple.ecore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IFile#getFullPath` to get relative path. You need to convert from `EObject` to `IFile` first.

#### Example:

```java
URI uri = EcoreUtil.getURI(eObject);
IPath path = new Path(uri.toFileString());
IFile file = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);

System.out.println(file.getFullPath()); // Relative path
```